# Why the equation $E(X \mid X=1000) = 1000$ is false, intuitively?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

In the life-long repeated struggle to understand the resolution of the [two envelops problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem), I finally found out the real crucial part is basically to understand why $E(X\mid X=1000)$ is not equal to $1000$, assuming you opened one of the envelop and found $500$ dollars inside.

However, intuitively how does this not be the case. I tried to find a concrete example where this equality does not hold but failed to do so. Indeed, there is no formula suggesting the equality to be true, but intuitively I am struggle to understand why this is not the case.

Edit: For more context, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgawcWisb0I), $X$ is somehow dependent with $X=1000$ and somehow this makes the equation false. However I am still struggling to understand the intuition without a concrete example.

Comment: The equation is true, and you can resolve the two envelopes problem regardless.

Comment: As far as I understand, the two envelops solution is true until the following equation: $E(X) = E(X\mid X=1000)\times {1\over2} + E(X \mid X=250)\times {1\over 2}$. It is the last step that sub in the $1000$ and $250$ to make the expected value $625 > 500$ which is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you should search for (or ask) a question about the two envelopes problem instead. I can't really answer your comment above without context. Regardless, the expectation statement you wrote in the title is correct (or  undefined if X can't be 1000).

Comment: Also see the answer to this meta question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: For context, I got the idea from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgawcWisb0I&t=764s), which is the most convincing one I have encountered so far. I have done endless searching about the problem and am pretty sure the fallacy lies on this last substitution step.

Comment: Refering to the video, the question I am asking has something to do with $X$ and $X=1000$ being dependent on each other. But I cannot find any concrete example whichis easy to understand intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement  $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y=1000] = 1000$ is correct, so long as the expectation is defined (i.e. it's possible that $Y=1000$.

The statement in the video, which is wrong, is different: $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y=2X] = \mathbb{E}[2X]$. The fact that we have $2X$ - another random variable - instead of $1000$ is key here.

A simple example is $X \in \{1,2\}$ with equal probability, and $Y = 3 - X$ (note, this is actually a special case of the two envelopes problem, with values 1 and 2).

Essentially, we have two cases: $X=1, Y=2$, and $X=2, Y=1$. Then $\mathbb{E}[2X] = 3$, while $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y=2X] = 2 \neq 3$, because only the first case $X=1, Y=2$ fits the condition.

We can correct the wrong statement as mentioned in the video: $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y=2X] = \mathbb{E}[2X | Y = 2X]$. In our example, $\mathbb{E}[2X | Y = 2X] = 2$ as well.

To get back to the original statement with 1000, we have: $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y = 1000] = \mathbb{E}[1000 | Y = 1000] = 1000$.

EDIT:

To clarify a bit on how that relates to the two envelopes problem, consider the full setup:

First, A chooses the pair of random variables $(X, Y)$ according to some distribution, such that $X=2Y$, or $Y=2X$. Puts $X$ in one envelope, and $Y$ in the other.

Now, B opens the first envelope and sees that $X=500$. How he knows that either $Y=250$, or $Y=1000$, and $\mathbb{E}[Y | X=500] = 250 \times \mathbb{P}[Y=250|X=500] + 1000 \times \mathbb{P}[Y=1000|X=500]$. With what we know so far we don't know the values of $\mathbb{P}[Y=250|X=500]$ and $\mathbb{P}[Y=1000|X=500]$. They depend on the distribution A used when choosing $(X, Y)$.

For example, suppose A chose a number uniformly between $0$ and $250$ for the smaller value. Then, if we open $X=500$, we know for sure that $Y=250$. Likewise, if A chose the smaller number to be uniformly between $500$ and $2000$, then if we opened $X=500$, we know for sure that $Y=1000$. And any case between these two extremes exists.

Now, in the two envelopes problem we're not told what the distribution of $(X, Y)$ is. This simply means that you can't compute $\mathbb{P}[Y=1000|X=500]$. You can't just assume it to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Contrast these two: $\mathbb{P}[Y=2X]$ and $\mathbb{P}[Y=2X | X=500]$. The first is $\frac{1}{2}$.  The second isn't, because the event $Y=2X$ is not independent of the value of $X$.

Comment: I see the difference. Does it mean when we open one envelop and found 500 dollars inside, the expected value of the other one is ACTUALLY 625? (Whereas before we open the envelop, the expected values are the same)

Comment: I also understood your example, which is essentially the same as the $X$ and $2X$ alternative solution. I understand that solution works without paradox but what I want to know is where exactly is the flaw in the "wrong" argument. When we opened one envelop and found $500$ dollars, I would say the two possible cases are $(250,500)$ and $(500,1000)$ instead of $(1000, 500)$ and $(500, 1000)$. I am still not convinced the fallacy lies in this step but rather in the step stated in the problem.

Comment: @cr001 Try setting everything up from the basics. Define your set of elementary events and compute the probabilities from there. If the cases (500, 250) and (500, 1000) have the same probability of occuring, then the expectation for $Y|X=500$ is indeed 625. Note that a uniform distribution over all positive numbers doesn't exist, so you can't have the same probability for every two pairs. If you don't know the distribution of $(X, Y)$, then you can't really tell the expectation of $Y|X=500$ - it depends on that distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I think I got the idea now. The explanation shown in the video is also wrong in that, the dependence not only changes the expectation but also the probability part. The video is wrong in stating that $E(X) = E(X\mid X=1000)\times {1\over2} + E(X \mid X=250)\times {1\over 2}$ in the first place because the probability cannot be $1\over 2$. Am I correct?

Comment: I have accepted the answer as the question itself is answered. In a situation that I found $500$ in my envelop and no other information is given, should the correct answer be $625$, or un-computable, or $500$?

Comment: @cr001 We don't have enough information in the two envelopes problem to compute it. I edited in more details in the answer. Note: I never saw the video  use a specific value such as 1000. It uses the random variables $X$ and $Y$ without conditioning on specific values. This is an important distinction, which makes the statement from the video $E(X) = E(X | X=2Y) \times \frac{1}{2} + E(X|X=Y/2)\times \frac{1}{2}$ correct, while the statement $E(X) = E(X | X=1000) \times \frac{1}{2} + E(X|X=250)\times \frac{1}{2}$ isn't,

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I am clear where exactly the fallacy is now. (I have come to this mind-state many times and then backtracked, hope this is the last time lol)